# Queue In Scala using list in scala

Tags: scala

We can implement a queue in java simply by using ArrayList but in case of Scala Lists are immutable so how can I implement a queue using List in Scala.Somebody give me some hint about it.

Comment: How about just using Scala [`Queue`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Queue) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With immutable Lists, you have to return a new List after any modifying operation. Once you've grasped that, it's straightforward. A minimal (but inefficient) implementation where the Queue is also immutable might be:

```
class Queue[T](content:List[T]) {
  def pop() =  new Queue(content.init)
  def push(element:T) = new Queue(element::content)
  def peek() = content.last

  override def toString() =  "Queue of:" + content.toString
}

val q=  new Queue(List(1)) //> q  : lists.queue.Queue[Int] = Queue of:List(1)
val r = q.push(2)          //> r  : lists.queue.Queue[Int] = Queue of:List(2, 1)
val s = r.peek()           //> s  : Int = 1
val t = r.pop()            //> t  : lists.queue.Queue[Int] = Queue of:List(2)
```

Comment: The advantage of the standard library's implementation with _two_ lists is that you get amortised constant costs for `pop` which in your example is not the case.

Comment: @0__, absolutely. The naive implementation is more obvious for explanatory purposes, though

Answer (score 6):

This is from Scala's [immutable Queue](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Queue):

> Queue is implemented as a pair of Lists, one containing the in elements and the other the out elements. Elements are added to the in list and removed from the out list. When the out list runs dry, the queue is pivoted by replacing the out list by in.reverse, and in by Nil.

So:

```
object Queue {
  def empty[A]: Queue[A] = new Queue(Nil, Nil)
}
class Queue[A] private (in: List[A], out: List[A]) {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = in.isEmpty && out.isEmpty

  def push(elem: A): Queue[A] = new Queue(elem :: in, out)

  def pop(): (A, Queue[A]) = 
    out match {
      case head :: tail => (head, new Queue(in, tail))
      case Nil =>
        val head :: tail = in.reverse  // throws exception if empty
        (head, new Queue(Nil, tail))
    }
}

var q = Queue.empty[Int]
(1 to 10).foreach(i => q = q.push(i))
while (!q.isEmpty) { val (i, r) = q.pop(); println(i); q = r }
```

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about `mutable` Lists, they wouldn't be an efficient structure for implementing a Queue for the following reason: Adding elements to the beginning of a list works very well (takes *constant time*), but popping elements off the end is not efficient at all (takes longer the more elements there are in the list).

You do, however, have Arrays in Scala.  Accessing any element in an array takes constant time.  Unfortunately arrays are not dynamically sized, so they wouldn't make good queues.  They cannot grow as your queue grows.  However [ArrayBuffers](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer) do grow as your array grows.  So that would be a great place to start.

Also, note that Scala already has a Queue class:  `scala.collection.mutable.Queue`.

The only way to implement a Queue with an `immutable` List would be to use a `var`.  Good luck!

Comment: but can u plz tell me how to implement them using List

Comment: You would need a var only if you want to implement a mutable queue using an immutable list, but would not if you want to implement an immutable queue.